# Convergence in distribution of distributions $p_n$ implies convergence in distribution of $s_n$?

Tags: probability, integration, functional-analysis, probability-theory, lebesgue-integral

### Question Setup

Suppose $p_n(x,y)$ is a sequence of probability densities on $\mathbb R^2$ and
$q_n(x)$ is a sequence of densities on $\mathbb R$ such that
\begin{align*}
  \int b(x,y) \ p_n(x,y) \ dx \ dy \to \int b(x,y) p_0(x,y) \ dx \ dy, 
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
  \int c(x) q_n(x) \ dx \to \int c(x) q_0(x) \ dx, 
\end{align*}
for every pair of bounded and continuous functions $b(x,y)$ and $c(x)$. In the
language of probability theory, we are saying that if $(X_n, Y_n) \sim p_n$ and
$(X, Y) \sim p_0$, then $(X_n, Y_n) \leadsto (X,Y)$ where "$\leadsto$" denotes
convergence in distribution. Similarly if $X_n \sim q_n$ and $X \sim q_0$ then
$X_n \leadsto X$.

Now, let $r_n(x)$ and $r_0(x)$ be the marginal densities of $\int p_n(x,y) \ dy$
and $\int p_0(x,y) \ dy$. Use these to define densities
\begin{align*}
  s_n(x,y) = \frac{q_n(x)}{r_n(x)} \times p_n(x,y), 
      \qquad s_0(x,y) = \frac{q_0(x)}{r_0(x)} \times p_0(x,y). 
\end{align*}

### My Question

My aim is to show that if $(X_n, Y_n) \sim s_n(x,y)$ and $(X, Y) \sim s_0(x,y)$,
then $(X_n, Y_n) \leadsto (X, Y)$. I know that, in general, this won't
happen. For example, I know this won't happen if $r_0(x)$ has a smaller support
than $q_0(x)$; similarly, I should expect that if $r_0(x)$ has a tails which
decay faster than $q_0(x)$ this won't happen. Therefore, I am willing to add the
following assumption:
\begin{align*}
  \sup_x \frac{q_0(x)}{r_0(x)} \le M, \qquad \text{for some $M \ge 0$}.
\end{align*}
Equivalently, I am asking that
\begin{align*}
  \int b(x,y) \frac{q_n(x)}{r_n(x)} p_n(x,y) \ dx \ dy 
    \to \int b(x,y) \frac{q_0(x)}{r_0(x)} p_o(x,y) \ dx \ dy,
\end{align*}
for all bounded and continuous functions $b(x,y)$.

If what I have given is not sufficient to prove the desired result, I am also
looking for conditions under which this does hold - feel free to add any
necessary conditions on $p_0(x,y)$ and $q_0(x)$ that you like. **If my aim is hopeless**, this is of interest as well.

It is
*essential* that there be no assumptions on $p_n$ and $q_n$ beyond the ones
I've given. For example, it is unacceptable to assume that there exists a
constant which bounds the ratios $q_n(x) / r_n(x)$ (of course, the result is
then trivial by dominated convergence). Another example of an unacceptable condition would be that the convergence occurs pointwise in the densities. Only restrictions on $p_0$ and $q_0$ are permissible. *Bonus points if you can weaken my current assumption*.